# How to fix location error using Win10 Edge to surf ingress.com/intel?

Tags: ingress

How do I fix a location error while browsing http://ingress.com/intel with Win10 Edge? It shows me about 5 miles west of my real location. This happens on my Lenovo X220i just upgraded from Win7 and my wife's Lenovo K450e upgraded from Win8.1. Neither system has GPS, but Opera, Chrome, and Firefox work just fine. Vivaldi doesn't get past nagging about enabling location (which is already enabled).

I'd like to give Edge a chance, but it lacks (or inobviously hides) much of the functionality of Opera.

Comment: First of all, your question is not about a game, but rather the attempt at accessing its site *outside* the game. Secondly, please ask your question on [su] as it's not directly about playing games and thirdly, does your computer have a GPS inside it? If not, the location shown is based on an estimate from your IP address and are *never* accurate.

Comment: @aytimothy First of all, higher level players know that <http://ingress.com/intel>  is an essential, indispensable part of strategizing the game. Note the domain name. Secondly, I play the game every day--it *is* directly about playing this game. Thirdly, neither affected system has GPS, but the location error in any of the other browsers listed is a few meters, as I would expect. Only in Edge (on both machines) is it eight kilometers--a thousandfold worse than any of the other browsers.

Comment: Edge is just Internet Explorer masked behind it.

Comment: I agree. The intel page is a pretty necessary component to the game, even if it isn't part of the actual app itself. Seems completely relevant here. However, browser compatibility gets into a weird area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a browser guesses your location based without GPS, it uses a database of IP addresses or wifi signals or whatever black magic is used.

Every browser uses a different database (because it's a huge investment and you don't really want to give that to another company).

Unfortunately there is no fixable error here, it is simply that the database is wrong for internet explorer. Use a different browser with a database that does give the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

You want intel to open displaying the location where you live, right ?

Open intel, move to the desired location (or search it), use "link" button to get the intel URL corresponding to that location, save it to your favorites.